# Can't run .run file using cygstart

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to run  a .run file in cygwin, but I always seem to get this error:

Unable to start '~.run': There is no application associated with the given file name extension.

I needed to be a superuser, so I tried using the command: cygstart --action=runas "$@"

I read somewhere that cygstart is for invoking registered Windows handler, so this may be the problem, but I am unsure. Is there any way that I can run my .run file as a superuser using cygwin?

Comment: What's inside that file? Is it some batch script or executable? Why don't you use appropriate extension? That means *cmd* / *bat* for batch script, *exe* for executable etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as has been said, no application is associated with `.run` files on your
system. So you can do that one of two ways

Call the file with the program, example

```
cygstart notepad.exe ~.run
```

Tell the registry what to do with unknown extensions

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown]
@=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell\Open\command]
@="notepad.exe \"%1\""
```

Comment: The first way simply opened the .run file using notepad. I actually wanted to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not related to Cygwin but rather to Windows. `cygstart` works the same as Windows' `start`. That means, if you use `[cyg]start file.extension` it works very similarly as if you double-click on that file in Windows Explorer.

Therefore if you configure Windows to do what you need when you double-click on your `*.run` file, `cygstart` will work fine too.

I think that easier is to use appropriate extension which Windows already knows. It depends on what you have inside your `*.run` file. If it's executable, use *exe* extension, if it's batch script, use *cmd* or *bat*, if it's JavaScript, use *js* etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux or some derivation, you need to execute the .run file with an absolute path, even if you have already navigated to the appropriate directory containing the file. See here:

http://the-chronicon.blogspot.com/2011/08/execute-run-file-in-current-folder-from.html